# What do you call the main part of a joke?

Tags: word-request

If I start a joke with a question, then answer it as part of a joke. What is the answer of the joke called? Is there a specific term for it? I am pretty sure there is, but can't remember what it was. Also, what if the main part of the joke isn't an answer? What would it still be called?

Comment: Previously at EL&U, *[What is the first part of a joke called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74406/)*

Comment: Can you provide the context for believing that there is a single word that would mean just this?

Comment: This question would have benefited from **an example**, as would almost all questions on this site.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the 'main' part (after all, the setup is just as important) but you're probably looking for the phrase *punch line* (also spelled as a [single word *punchline*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/punchline)):

> the sentence, statement, or phrase (as in a joke) that makes the point

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punch%20line))</sub>

It's often used for jokes which are like short stories; I'm not entirely sure if it applies to Q&A jokes as well (I'm not a native speaker).

Comment: And for the record, the first part of the joke also has a name: The "setup".

Comment: I'd say Q&A style jokes are some of the easiest to determine what the punchline is.  For a simple example, in "Why is six afraid of seven?", you would call "Because seven eight nine!" the punchline because you could say it is the sentence/statement/phrase that makes it a joke.

Comment: @Glorfindel I can't think of any rule that absolutely defines what counts as a "line" in English (or the origin of "punchline").  Presumably, if it's anything like scripts, what constitutes a "line" has nothing really to do with how many words the line is.  Also, I would say a single word can still be a statement, so it can fit your definitions still.

Comment: To build on what JMac said in reply to @Glorfindel. "Punchline" and "setup" don't even have to refer to words at all and can apply to jokes that are entirely non-linguistic. When someone says "Pull my finger", that is the setup, and the ensuing fart is the punchline.

Comment: For example if you go to a ball, there would be a line to hire a tuxedo, a line to hire a car, a line for the girl you want to ask out but hopefully there won't be a punchline.

Answer (score 34):

The other part (which may be the *long* part, so it may count as the "main" part to some) is the **Setup**.

I found a [Glossary of Comedy Terminology](http://www.comicalmanagement.com/pages/comical-terminology), if you have other humor-related questions.

---

I re-read and saw you were answering about the "punchline" area -- I think it's not so much that this second part is an "answer," but that it typically changes/challenges the audience's assumptions.

In the one liner: "Take my wife... please!" the assumption at the start is "I've got a good example about someone who does something stereotypical, my wife."  But then with the "please!" it changes from an introduction to a longer section, to a direct, imperative command.  Take her. Now. Make her go away.  It's not pretty, but it's a change-in-direction, and that's what made it "work."

Some related terms from the Comedy Glossary that may help identify these parts of the joke:

> **Decoy Assumption** - the misdirecting assumption in a joke's setup which creates the 1st story and is shattered by the reinterpretation.
>
> **Connector** - at the center of a joke, the one thing perceived in at least two ways.  One way of perceiving it constitutes the decoy assumption; the second way of perceiving it reveals the reinterpretation.
>
> **Shatter** - with reference to joke structure, the point at which the  audience realized that their assumption is incorrect.
>
> **Punch** or **Punch Line** - the second part of a joke that contains a reinterpretation that creates a 2nd story that shatters  the setup's decoy assumption.
>
> **Reveal** - within the punch, the pivotal word, phrase, or action that exposes or presents the 2nd story's reinterpretation.
>
> **Tag** or **Tag Line** - an additional punch immediately following a punch that does not require a new setup

Answer (score 5):

As everyone else has said, the bit at the end that (hopefully) causes the audience to collapse in fits of laughter is known as the *punchline.*

If it's a more lengthy humorous story with lots of funny bits, but either a weak punchline, or no punchline, or a more serious point at the end treated lightly by what came before, then the whole thing may be a [shaggy dog story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story), which Wikipedia defines as:

> an extremely long-winded anecdote characterized by extensive narration of typically irrelevant incidents and terminated by an anticlimax or a pointless punchline.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I didn't properly read what Glorfindel said, but he's right. My bad, sorry.

I would say this is still called a punchline: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/punchline

"The last part of a story or a joke that explains the meaning of what has happened previously or makes it funny".

It's usually what finishes off the joke and makes people laugh.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was *"it's a **call-and-response** joke."*  If you wanted to go with that, your answer would be: **the response.**

I had a similar question, *"what do you call this type of joke?"*, which led me here.  I think I found the best answer to that buried in this fascinating [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Yo_mama%22_joke) which refers to this article, [*This Tablet From 1,500 B.C. May Contain The World’s First “Yo Mama” Joke*](https://allthatsinteresting.com/historys-first-yo-mama-joke): **a riddle.**

Depending on the context, you could refer to such a joke as a **"yo mama,"** a **"what do you call a *this* who *that*,"** or a **"what do you get when you"** joke.  To get academic about it, you could go with an **"interrogative,"** an **"interactive interrogative,"** a **"Q&A,"** or (to get ridiculously meticulous about it) a **"Q&RQ&A"** ("question, response question, answer") joke.  For example:

**Q**: What do you call a person who comes up with a question similar to yours, uses it as a search string, finds this thread on StackExchange, and pounces on the opportunity to procrastinate?
**RQ**: I don't know, what *do* you [etc.]?
**A**: Obsessive compulsive!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is my response unclear?  I believe I answered the question in my first paragraph.